# Multiple DHCP REQUESTs from the same box - with address provided

Tags: dhcp

Please share how to stop/block/identify the rogue device. Lease time is 1 hour. Eventually I may run out of addresses.
Attached is log data. My DHCP server provides an address to the Windows 2003 Server **SARDIS2**. I'm not clear on the long (16 byte) MAC address.

```
Mar 16 11:53:15 croghan.birchard.org bootpd[1700]: DHCP REQUEST [en0]: 1,52:41:53:20:d0:67:e5:ed:9f:2:0:0:9:0:0:0 <SARDIS2>
Mar 16 11:53:15 croghan.birchard.org bootpd[1700]: dhcpd: 192.168.1.49 lease extended to INIT/REBOOT client
Mar 16 11:53:15 croghan.birchard.org bootpd[1700]: replying using broadcast IP address
Mar 16 11:53:15 croghan.birchard.org bootpd[1700]: replying to 255.255.255.255
Mar 16 11:53:15 croghan.birchard.org bootpd[1700]: ACK sent SARDIS2 192.168.1.49 pktsize 300
Mar 16 11:53:15 croghan.birchard.org bootpd[1700]: service time 0.001959 seconds
Mar 16 11:53:15 croghan.birchard.org bootpd[1700]: DHCP REQUEST [en0]: 1,52:41:53:20:d0:67:e5:ed:9f:2:0:0:8:0:0:0 <SARDIS2>
Mar 16 11:53:15 croghan.birchard.org bootpd[1700]: dhcpd: 192.168.1.50 lease extended to INIT/REBOOT client
Mar 16 11:53:15 croghan.birchard.org bootpd[1700]: replying using broadcast IP address
Mar 16 11:53:15 croghan.birchard.org bootpd[1700]: replying to 255.255.255.255
Mar 16 11:53:15 croghan.birchard.org bootpd[1700]: ACK sent SARDIS2 192.168.1.50 pktsize 300
Mar 16 11:53:15 croghan.birchard.org bootpd[1700]: service time 0.001705 seconds
Mar 16 11:53:15 croghan.birchard.org bootpd[1700]: DHCP REQUEST [en0]: 1,52:41:53:20:d0:67:e5:ed:9f:2:0:0:7:0:0:0 <SARDIS2>
Mar 16 11:53:15 croghan.birchard.org bootpd[1700]: dhcpd: 192.168.1.51 lease extended to INIT/REBOOT client
Mar 16 11:53:15 croghan.birchard.org bootpd[1700]: replying using broadcast IP address
Mar 16 11:53:15 croghan.birchard.org bootpd[1700]: replying to 255.255.255.255
Mar 16 11:53:15 croghan.birchard.org bootpd[1700]: ACK sent SARDIS2 192.168.1.51 pktsize 300
Mar 16 11:53:15 croghan.birchard.org bootpd[1700]: service time 0.001372 seconds
Mar 16 11:53:15 croghan.birchard.org bootpd[1700]: DHCP REQUEST [en0]: 1,52:41:53:20:d0:67:e5:ed:9f:2:0:0:6:0:0:0 <SARDIS2>
Mar 16 11:53:15 croghan.birchard.org bootpd[1700]: dhcpd: 192.168.1.52 lease extended to INIT/REBOOT client
Mar 16 11:53:15 croghan.birchard.org bootpd[1700]: replying using broadcast IP address
Mar 16 11:53:15 croghan.birchard.org bootpd[1700]: replying to 255.255.255.255
Mar 16 11:53:15 croghan.birchard.org bootpd[1700]: ACK sent SARDIS2 192.168.1.52 pktsize 300
Mar 16 11:53:15 croghan.birchard.org bootpd[1700]: service time 0.001852 seconds
Mar 16 11:53:15 croghan.birchard.org bootpd[1700]: DHCP REQUEST [en0]: 1,52:41:53:20:d0:67:e5:ed:9f:2:0:0:5:0:0:0 <SARDIS2>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not geared to solve your long term problem, but in the short term drop your lease time to something really low. Those requests are coming in quickly.

Next step is to hop on a switch and look at arp tables for the MAC address that is making the request. Then you can identify the switch port. On some switch gear, it is: show arp or show mac-address-table

You are going to have to look it up. You can begin to interrogate your switch gear to pinpoint the offending device.